# convert array list -> map using java 8

Tags: java, java-8

i've been trying to figure out how to use java 8 streams to create a map like the one created by getCardValueCountMap method below:

```
public class Hand {
        private final List<Card> hand = new ArrayList<>();
        .....
        public Map<CardValue, Integer> getCardValueCountMap(){
            HashMap<CardValue, Integer> cardValueCountMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (Card card : hand) {
                final CardValue value = card.getValue();
                Integer count = cardValueCountMap.get(value);
                if (count == null){
                   cardValueCountMap.put(value, 1);
                } else {
                   cardValueCountMap.put(value, count + 1);
                }
            }
            return cardValueCountMap;
         }
....
}
```

Comment: That code already is Java 8... You mean using streams?

Comment: _I've been trying_...doesn't show what they tried. Smells like _do-my-work-for-me_.

Comment: There are like 5 duplicates in the Related tab on the right.

Comment: It is the count part that i'm having trouble with hand.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Card::getValue, ??));..  I'm using intellij and it can't resolve getValue, plus i don't know how to get the count feature.

Comment: See the linked question, a great solution is to group by `Card::getValue` and count as downstream.

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/q/29122394/1743880

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't use streams, so isn't really an answer to your question, but in my opinion the cleanest way to do this is to take advantage of the improvements to the `Map` interface.

```
HashMap<CardValue, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Card card : hand)
    map.merge(card.getValue(), 1, Integer::sum);
```

Comment: I like that. Alternatives: `hand.stream().collect(toMap(Card::getValue, c -> 1, Integer::sum));` -- `hand.stream().collect(groupingBy(Card::getValue, counting()));`.