# Best way to find a list of words and its count from a large string in Java?

Tags: java, guava

I have a list of words, lets say

- Spring Data
- Java
- C++
- Junit

and I have a very large text in a file or String

I need to find out for every word in my list, how many occurrences of that word found in that large string?

I am kind of expecting result as

- Spring Data(10)
- Java (3)
- C++ (6)
- Junit (0)

The above is just 4 elements, however in my case it may go up to few thousands, i could traverse each element and find the no.of count against that string, but not sure that would a best solution considering the performance? Can you guys shed  me some light on for the best way to find this out?

Comment: there are several algorithms that aim at making text-searches more efficient. look into "Boyer-Moore" or "Karp and Rabin". maybe this helps.

Comment: `str.split("\\s+")` then see [word-frequency-count-java-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122394)

Comment: Do you need words or phrases? "Spring" is a word while "Spring Data" is a phrase (i.e. a non-empty list of words, i.e one or more words ordered together).

Comment: Define "word".  Do you have a list of words?  A string to be split by spaces?

Comment: @mfulton26, You are correct, I probabbly should have mentioned as phrases. basically i have list of phrases and need to find the count of the each phrase against a large string

Answer (score 1):

Given the need to match strings that contain spaces, I would tend to go with looping through your list of target strings, doing an appropriately escaped regex search in the text for that string, and recording the number of regex matches.

Comment: Sure thanks, yes that seems to be the sensible thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of `strings` by splitting the main `string` by white space and using Java 8's Stream API, eg.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String s = "a b c d e f d g e a c v d a w s";
    Map<String, Long> wordCount = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s"))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(wordCount);
}
```

Comment: This uses many times the storage of the original string. For very large strings (as per the question) this could be a problem. An inputstream approach, which uses O(1) space, would be better suited.

Comment: That would be a premature optimization. Always try the simple approach first. Computers have lots of ram these days.

Comment: Thanks Darshan, but unfortunately I can't split by space  ad my search string may contain a word with space....

Comment: @EnthuLeo So, how are you going to differentiate/split the words? I guess if a word contains a space then it's two words?

Comment: @bhspencer this is exactly same as what you have written in your answer. Just that `stream` approach saves us from writing a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: @DarshanMehta, Probabbly I should have mentioned as phrases. basically i have list of phrases and need to find the count of the each phrase against a large string.

Comment: An external loop isn't boilerplate code it is just a different style. I would argue that your code is less implicitly understandable. e.g. you need to know in advance what the params are to groupingBy() and you need to know the meaning of Function.identity() and Collectors.counting(). Also stepping through stream based code in a debugger is a thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Streams you can do it this way:

```
    String s = "a b c d e f d g e a c v d a w s";
    Map<String, Long> wordCount = new HashMap<>();
    String[] words = s.split("\\s");
    for (String word : words) {
        Long count = wordCount.get(word);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0L;
        }
        count = count + 1L;
        wordCount.put(word, count);
    }
    System.out.println(wordCount);
```

Comment: You forgot to increment count. `count = 0L; wordCount.put(word, count + 1);`

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You need to set the initial count to 0 if it didn't exist, otherwise you are jumping right to 2 on the first occurrence.