# How can I find the most frequent word in a huge amount of words (eg. 900000)

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, collections

I am facing a task which is generating 900000 random words and then print out the most frequent one. So here is my algorithm:

```
1. move all number into a collection rather than printhing out them
2. for (900000...){move the frequency of Collection[i] to another collection B}
** 90W*90W is too much for a computer(lack of efficiency)
3. find the biggest number in that collection and the index.
4. then B[index] is output.
```

But the thing is that my computer cannot handle the second step. So I searched on this website and find some answer about find the frequency of word in a bunch of words and I viewed the answer code, but I haven't find a way to apply them into huge amount of words.

Now I show my code here:

```
/** Funny Words Generator
  * Tony
  */

import java.util.*;

public class WordsGenerator {

  //data field (can be accessed in whole class):
  private static int xC; // define a xCurrent so we can access it all over the class
  private static int n;
  private static String[] consonants = {"b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","r","s","t","v","w","x","z"};
  private static String[] vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};
  private static String funnyWords = "";



  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int times = 900000; // words number
    xC = sc.nextInt(); // seeds (only input)

    /* Funny word list */
    ArrayList<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> frequencies = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int maxFreq;
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      n = 6; // each words are 6 characters long
      funnyWords = ""; // reset the funnyWords each new time
      for (int d = 0; d < n; d ++) {

        int letterNum = randomGenerator(); /* random generator will generate numbers based on current x */
        int letterIndex = 0; /* letterNum % 19 or % 5 based on condition */

        if ((d + 1) % 2 == 0) {
          letterIndex = letterNum % 5;
          funnyWords += vowels[letterIndex];
        }

        else if ((d + 1) % 2 != 0) {
          letterIndex = letterNum % 19;
          funnyWords += consonants[letterIndex];
        }
      }
      wordsList.add(funnyWords);
    }


    /* put all frequencies of each words into an array called frequencies */
    for (int i = 0; i < 900000; i++) {
      frequencies.add(Collections.frequency(wordsList, wordsList.get(i)));
    }



    maxFreq = Collections.max(frequencies);
    int index = frequencies.indexOf(maxFreq); // get the index of the most frequent word
    System.out.print(wordsList.get(index));


    sc.close();
  }

  /** randomGenerator
    * param: N(generate times), seeds
    * return: update the xC and return it */
  private static int randomGenerator() {
    int a = 445;
    int c = 700001;
    int m = 2097152;
    xC = (a * xC + c) % m; // update
    return xC; // return
  }

}
```

So I have realized that maybe there is a way skip the second step somehow. Anyone can give me a hint? Just a hint not code so I can try it myself will be great! Thx!

Modified:
I see lots of your answer code contains "words.stream()", I googled it and I couldn't find it. Could you guys please tell me where I can find this kind of knowledge? this stream method is in which class? Thank you!

Comment: Using Lists will be very slow for this. There are a lot of other collections to consider.

Comment: Why don't you try 1.) Move words to list, 2.) sort list (Collections.sort), 3.) go through the list elements and every time the current word is the same as the previous one increase a counter. When current word is different, then check if you need to update the maxFrequency, and reset the counter to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HashMap is one of the fastest data structures, just loop through each words, use it as key to the HashMap, inside the loop, make the counter the value of the hashMap.

```
HashMap<string, Integer> hashMapVariable = new HashMap<>();
...
//inside the loop of words
if (hashMapVariable.containsKey(word){
   hashMapVariable.put(key, hashMapVariable.get(key) + 1);
} else {
   hashMapVariable.put(word, 1);
}
...
```

for each key(word) just increment the value as associated with the key. although you have to check if the key exits ( in java its `hashMapVariable.containsKey("key")` ). if its exits then just increament else add it to the HashMap. by doing this you are not restoring the whole data you are only making every key just one and the number of times it occurs as value to the key.

At the end of the loop the most frequent word will have the highest counter/value.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I wonder only one thing: how can I `check if the key already exist`? Should I create another list to store the words already iterated?

Comment: @TonyChen, just updated my answer to explain, how you can achieve this

Comment: let me know if this help you or i can quickly crack up the code to it

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using Java Lambdas (requires JDK 8). Also notice that you can have words with equal frequency in your word list.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

        words.add("World");
        words.add("Hello");
        words.add("World");
        words.add("Hello");

        // Imagine we have 90000 words in word list
        Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> set = words.stream()
                // Here we create map of unique words and calculates their frequency
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(word -> word, word -> 1, Integer::sum)).entrySet();

        // Find the max frequency
        int max = Collections
                .max(set, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.getValue(), b.getValue())).getValue();

        // We can have words with the same frequency like in my words list. Let's get them all
        List<String> list = set.stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == max)
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(list); // [Hello, World]


    }
}
```

Comment: One up for the tie-breaking. It's definitely something that should be considered, at least.

Answer (score 2):

This can basically be broken down into two steps:

1. Compute the word frequencies, as a `Map<String, Long>`. There are several options for this, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29122394/3182664) for examples.
2. Computing the maximum entry of this map, where "maximum" refers to the entry with the highest value.

So if you're really up to it, you can write this very compactly:

```
private static <T> T maxCountElement(List<? extends T> list)
{
    return Collections.max(list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())).entrySet(), 
            (e0, e1) -> Long.compare(e0.getValue(), e1.getValue())).getKey();
}
```

---

**Edited** in response to the comment:

The compact representation may not be the most readable. Breaking it down makes the code a bit elaborate, but may make clearer what is happening there:

```
private static <T> T maxCountElement(List<? extends T> list)
{
    // A collector that receives the input elements, and converts them 
    // into a map. The key of the map is the input element. The value 
    // of the map is the number of occurrences of the element
    Collector<T, ?, Map<T, Long>> collector = 
        Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting());

    // Create the map and obtain its set of entries
    Map<T, Long> map = list.stream().collect(collector);
    Set<Entry<T, Long>> entrySet = map.entrySet();

    // A comparator that compares two map entries based on their value
    Comparator<Entry<T, Long>> comparator = 
        (e0, e1) -> Long.compare(e0.getValue(), e1.getValue());

    // Compute the maximum element of the set of entries. That is,
    // the entry with the largest value (which is the entry for the
    // element with the maximum number of occurrences)
    Entry<T, Long> entryWithMaxValue = 
        Collections.max(entrySet, comparator);

    return entryWithMaxValue.getKey();
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I assume the code you provide me is effective, but I don't understand lots of methods in the code you provide me as a junior student in college. Can you give me some advice that where I can find those information? I try to use the docs on Oracle but it's too overwhelming cuz it generates more problems in the explanation... Thank you!

Comment: @TonyChen You should read something about Java Lambdas and Functional Programming at all. Once you understand it you will fall in love with it for ever

Comment: @DmitrySoroka Thanks for ur recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `HashMap` and the `key` store *word* and the value is `correspond times`

pseudocode as below:

```
String demo(){
   int maxFrequency = 0;
   String maxFrequencyStr = "";
   String strs[] ;
   Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
   for(int i = 0; i < 900000;i++){//for
      if(map.containsKey(strs[i])){
          int times = map.get(strs[i]);
          map.put(strs[i], times+1);
          if(maxFrequency<times+1){
              maxFrequency = times + 1;
              maxFrequencyStr = strs[i];
          }
      }
      else{
          map.put(strs[i], 1);
          if(maxFrequency<1){
              maxFrequency = 1;
              maxFrequencyStr = strs[i];
          }
      }
   }//for
   return maxFrequencyStr;
 }
```