# Java 8 Object stream to map trouble

Tags: java, list, object, dictionary, java-stream

first post here on stack overflow.
In Java, i'm trying to build a Map that maps to each different String the number of times it occurs. The following is the code of my class defining the objects in my List Data;

```
public class MonitoredData {
public String activityLabel;
public LocalTime startTime, endTime;
public LocalTime Period;
public LocalDate startDate, endDate;
long seconds;
public MonitoredData(LocalDateTime _st, LocalDateTime  _et, String _al){
    startTime=_st.toLocalTime();
    endTime=_et.toLocalTime();
    startDate=_et.toLocalDate();
    endDate=_st.toLocalDate();
    activityLabel=_al;
    Period=LocalTime.from(endTime);
    Period=Period.minusHours(_st.getHour());
    Period=Period.minusMinutes(_st.getMinute());
    Period=Period.minusSeconds(_st.getSecond());
    seconds=Period.getHour()*3600+Period.getMinute()*60+Period.getSecond();
}
```

From this list, i'm trying to build a map that counts the number of occurences of each string, namely activityLabel.
I hope i've been clear enough, thank you. The stream should map to activityLabel string and simply count occurences of each different activityLabel string in the list of objects.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122394/word-frequency-count-java-8), which sort of resembles what i want, but i still couldn't get it to work, and it's been bugging me for almost a day now.
   This is the first thing i tried, since it seemed to be working for a string object.
`Map<String, Long> collect = 
        wordsList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));`

However, after seeing that it doesn't compile, i tried randomly tweaking stuff around, not really getting what's going on.
   I read [this](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/) entire thing, and i can't say i haven't learnt anything, but i still didn't find my answer.

Comment: What have you done yourself? You say you've been trying for a day, but don't really show much evidence of that - do you have a specific question relating to what you've tried, or are you just asking someone to write the code for you?

Comment: What did you try exactly? What was the problem?

Comment: I used time and date separately to be able to more easily edit the dates and times around, i was not aware of the between function, looked it up just now.

Comment: @Diliglont you can't edit the dates and times, they are immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments on the code you've shown.

- Why do you store the time and dates separately and not the LocalDateTimes directly?
- `Period=LocalTime.from(endTime); is unnecessary:`LocalTime` is immutable.
- Period is a field and should start in lower case.
- You probably want to write seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(startTime, endTime) instead of your complicated calculation.
- You should probably make your field `private` (at least, and `final` if appropriate)

So your class could look like this:

```
public class MonitoredData {
  private final String activityLabel;
  private final LocalDateTime start;
  private final LocalDateTime end;
  private final long seconds;

  public MonitoredData(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end, String activityLabel) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.activityLabel = activityLabel;
    this.seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(start.toLocalTime(), end.toLocalTime());
  }

  public String getActivityLabel() {
    return activityLabel;
  }

  //other getters
}
```

And your counting operation would look like:

```
List<MonitoredData> list = ...;
Map<String, Long> activityCount = list.stream()
                            .map(MonitoredData::getActivityLabel)
                            .collect(groupingBy(al -> al, counting()));
```

(requires static imports: `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;` and `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;`).

Comment: Okay that looks much better. In my original code Period was the difference between start times and end times, how can i do that in a more elegant way? I'm gonna suppose start.minus(end) will not work towards resulting a difference between them as a LocalDateTime object.

Comment: @Diliglont You may want to look at `Duration`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html

Answer (score 1):

You can map the elements in the list to `String`, using the *activityLabel* attribute, then use `groupingBy` to group the same strings and `counting` to get their counts.

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
List<MonitoredData> data = Arrays.asList(new MonitoredData(now, now, "foo"),
        new MonitoredData(now, now, "foo"), new MonitoredData(now, now, "bar"),
        new MonitoredData(now, now, "foo"), new MonitoredData(now, now, "blub"));

Map<String, Long> counts = data.stream()
        .map(md -> md.activityLabel)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(counts);
// {bar=1, foo=3, blub=1}
```