# Count and list occurrences inside list ordering count by DESC

Tags: java, list

Here is my function:

```
public static void countKeywords(List<String> list) {
    Map<String, Long> counts =
            list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(counts);
}
```

And here is the sample that it outputs:

```
{alarm=2, player=1, factory=3}
```

I need it to be ordered by occurrence count in descending direction. So output must be like:

```
  factory - 3
  alarm - 2
  player - 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try using Collections.sort?

Comment: @ZeldaZach where exactlly?

Comment: I feel like this is a homework problem of some kind, so I'll let you figure that part out :)

Comment: I mark it as duplicate of Java 8 Wordcount https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122394/word-frequency-count-java-8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word frequency count Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122394/word-frequency-count-java-8)

Comment: It's not duplicate of words count because this work there, the question is how to sort DESC ^^

Comment: @ZeldaZach it's not homework. I did tons of research. Can't find any result

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the data structure your using. A normal map does not guarantee order or sorting. If your set on using a Map as your structure, I would take a look at the TreeMap API. It lets you define a comparator in your map constructor.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

```
public static void countKeywords(List<String> list) {
    Map<String, Long> counts = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(counts);

    TreeMap<String, Long> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, Long>(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String key1, String key2) {
            return counts.get(key2).compareTo(counts.get(key1));
        }
    });

    sortedMap.putAll(counts);
    System.out.println(sortedMap);
}
```