# Is there a more efficient way to make HashMap with a counter from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap, counter

I have a method that allows me to create a `HashMap` from an `ArrayList` by getting the `AirbnbListing` object then comparing the neighbourhood name with any keys in the `HashMap`. If its not already in the hashmap I add it with a counter starting at 1 if it already exists I increment the counter.

Is there a more efficient way to do this here is my code:

```
    public HashMap<String, Integer> sortHousesInNbrhood(ArrayList<AirbnbListing> priceRangeListing) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> housesInNbrhood = new HashMap<>();
    for (AirbnbListing listing : priceRangeListing) {
        if (housesInNbrhood.isEmpty()) {
            housesInNbrhood.put(listing.getNeighbourhood(), 1); 
        } else if (housesInNbrhood.containsKey(listing.getNeighbourhood())) {
            housesInNbrhood.replace(listing.getNeighbourhood(), housesInNbrhood.get(listing.getNeighbourhood()) + 1);
        } else {
            housesInNbrhood.put(listing.getNeighbourhood(),1); 
        }
    }

    return housesInNbrhood;
}
```

Comment: Question here is, what would be "more efficient" for you? Faster execution time? Smaller amounts of compiled bytecode? There are a lot of metrics to apply for efficiency.

Comment: With today's server resources being plentiful, do consider that a little more code for readability is fine (where it is more readable). Because it is inefficient to cause devs (including yourself months later) to wonder what the code does because you tried too hard to thin it down to "clever" shortenings.

Comment: Ah i'll modify my question preferably faster execution time.

Comment: That's what I mean though. If it's more readable do that, if it's the same and less code do that. If it's less readable then don't do it because the nanoseconds you save on execution time is trivial compared to potentially causing dev time to have to figure something out that was otherwise perfectly fine :)

Comment: There are different options for solving this that do not differ sooo much in readability, but may differ *significantly* in performance. I did a comparison for the different options for a very similar case in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29127257/3182664

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector with [`counting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--) as the downstream collector:

```
priceRangeListing.stream()
                 .collect(groupingBy(AirbnbListing::getNeighbourhood, counting()));
```

Note, the above will yield a `Map<String, Long>` but if you really want `Map<String, Integer>` then use the [`summingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) collector as the downstream:

```
priceRangeListing.stream()
       .collect(groupingBy(AirbnbListing::getNeighbourhood, summingInt(e -> 1)));
```

Comment: When its "collecting" how do i know its being collected into map?

Comment: @LogiGunaratnam `groupingBy` returns a `Map<AirbnbListing, Long>`

Comment: @LogiGunaratnam what Lino said is correct. just to expand on that `groupingBy` will always return a map, but to decide what type of map the results are being collected into, you'll need to use a different variant of the `groupingBy` e.g. `priceRangeListing.stream()
                 .collect(groupingBy(AirbnbListing::getNeighbourhood, HashMap::new, counting()));`

Comment: @Lino minor but I am sure you meant `Map<String, Long>` as opposed to `Map<AirbnbListing, Long>`.

Comment: @LogiGunaratnam the type of map for the first example is `Map<String, Long>` as mentioned and the second is `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: @Aominè yep you're right, I meant that, but somehow messed that up still :)

Comment: It is worth mentioning, that you will need
`import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;` to get this code compiled.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch I assumed any modern IDE would suggest the right import but that's a good shout!, thanks.

Comment: If I wanted to return it as HashMap can i just cast to a HashMap or is that bad practice?

Comment: @LogiGunaratnam you need not cast anything, simply use the `groupingBy` overload that allows you to specify the map you want e.g. `priceRangeListing.stream() .collect(groupingBy(AirbnbListing::getNeighbourhood, HashMap::new, counting()));` will return a `HashMap<String, Long>`

Answer (score 1):

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> sortHousesInNbrhood(ArrayList<AirbnbListing> priceRangeListing) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> housesInNbrhood = new HashMap<>();
    for (AirbnbListing listing : priceRangeListing) {
         housesInNbrhood.compute(listing.getNeighbourhood(), (k, v) -> (v == null) ? 1 : v + 1);
    }

    return housesInNbrhood;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Multiset`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) are datastructures that are specialised to keep track of the number of times object occur in a set. They are a perfect fit for your problem!

They are not available in the Java standard libraries, but they are in the Guava library.

I suggest that you replace `HashMap` as the return value of your method with `Multiset`. It that case it will be more clear to readers what it contains.

With that solution the code looks like this:

```
public Multiset<String> sortHousesInNbrhood(List<AirbnbListing> priceRangeListing) {
    Multiset<String> housesInNbrhood = TreeMultiset.create();
    // Multimap automatically counts the number of times an object have been added
    priceRangeListing.forEach(list -> housesInNbrhood.add(list.getNeighbourhood()));
    return housesInNbrhood;
}

// Use the multiset like this:
public void useMultiset(List<AirbnbListing> priceRangeListing) {
    Multiset<String> s = sortHousesInNbrhood(priceRangeListing);
    System.out.println("Houses in Bagdad:" + s.count("Bagdad"));

    System.out.println("All counts: ");
    for (Entry<String> e : s.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getElement() + ": " + e.getCount());
    }
}
```

---

If you have to return a `HashMap` then you can construct it from the `Multiset` like this:

```
public Map<String, Integer> sortHousesInNbrhood_2(List<AirbnbListing> priceRangeListing) {
    Multiset<String> housesInNbrhood = TreeMultiset.create();
    priceRangeListing.forEach(list -> housesInNbrhood.add(list.getNeighbourhood()));
    return housesInNbrhood.entrySet().stream().collect(toMap(Entry::getElement, Entry::getCount));
}
```

---

Multisets and multimaps are some of my favourite datastructures. So convenient!