# How to search a LinkedList for a specific word and return where it is in the list and how many times it appears

Tags: java, java-8, linked-list

I am having an issue in that I need to search a linked list that I have created and output how many times the specified word appears and where in the list the word appears. This is all done in a Java GUI where the input for the specific word is done using a textfield. The specific button I'm having trouble with in my code is the 'searchList' button I have already added code into it however I'm still not getting the result I need.

Any help with this would be appreciated!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
FilledFrame frame = new FilledFrame();

frame.setVisible( true );
frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setTitle("Word List");
}
}

class  FilledFrame extends JFrame{
JLabel     addWord;
JTextField addW;
JTextArea wordArea;

// Creating linked list
private LinkedList<String> wordList = new LinkedList();

public FilledFrame(){

    //Create JTextArea
    wordArea                = new JTextArea();

    //Create all the buttons, JLabel and the JPanel
    JButton addButton       = new JButton("Add Word");
    JButton specifiedLetter = new JButton("Display Specific Letter");
    JButton searchList      = new JButton("Search List");
    JButton removeLastOcc   = new JButton("Remove Last");
    JButton removeAll       = new JButton("Remove All Word Occurrence's ");
    JButton clearList       = new JButton("Clear List");

    JPanel panel            = new JPanel();

    //Add buttons and label to the window

    panel.add(addButton);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    panel.add(specifiedLetter);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    panel.add(searchList);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    panel.add(removeLastOcc);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    panel.add(removeAll);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    panel.add(clearList);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    //Create all Text Fields and Labels
     addWord          = new JLabel("Enter word");

     addW             = new JTextField(20);

    JPanel panel1     = new JPanel();

    //Add labels and text fields to the window
    panel1.add(addWord);
    add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panel1.add(addW);
    add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    //Add JTextArea to the center and make sure user cannot type into it
    add(wordArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    wordArea.setEditable( false );


    //  Action listeners for each button

    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            wordList.add((addW.getText()));
            wordArea.setText(" The word " + addW.getText() + " was added to the list ");
            System.out.println(wordList);
        }
    });

    specifiedLetter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        }
    });

    //The button I am having trouble with

    searchList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String showWord = "";
            TreeMap<String, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();

            if ((addW.getText()).length() < 1){
               for(String word : wordList)
               {
                    treeMap.put(word, 1);
                    treeMap.keySet().contains(word);

                    if (treeMap.containsKey(word)) {
                        treeMap.replace(word, treeMap.get(word)+1);
                    }
                    else{
                        treeMap.put(word, 1);
                    }
               }

                wordArea.setText(showWord);
                for (String word: wordList){
                    System.out.println(" This word appears " + word);
                }

            }

            }


        });
```

Comment: you could also just search for word count examples ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the whole logic you wrote with a simple line, using a `Collector` from java 8:

```
 Map<String, Long> collect = list.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Here you will get a `Map<String, Long>` with key being the word and value how many times it does repeat.

To find where it appears, you can iterate through list and find the first occurrence of the word from map you just created.

Comment: I'd call it a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122394/word-frequency-count-java-8) ...

Comment: To find where it appears (as originally asked by OP) you'll have to iterate the collections twice, while both loops can be combined into a single one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
         .forEach(i -> {
             map.computeIfAbsent(list.get(i), s -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i);
         });
```

It will store all the indices in a map of lists. Now you can easily get the indices by `map.get(str)` or the count of occurances by `map.get(str).size()`.

Note that this solution performs all the actions at once. So you don't need to iterate any collections twice.